# Memory Leak(?) with StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a few very large files each of `500MB++` size, containing integer values (in fact it's a bit more complex), I'm reading those files in a loop and calculating the max value for all files. By some reason the memory is growing constantly during the processing, it looks like GC never releases the memory, acquired by the previous instances of `lines`.

I cannot stream the data and have to use `GetFileLines` for each file. Provided the actual amount of memory required to store `lines` for one file is `500MB`, why do I get `5GB` of `RAM` used after 10 files being processed? Eventually it crashes with Out of Memory exception after 15 files.

Calculation:

```
   int max = int.MinValue;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      IEnumerable<string> lines = Db.GetFileLines(i);

      max = Math.Max(max, lines.Max(t=>int.Parse(t)));
   }
```

GetFileLines code:

```
   public static List<string> GetFileLines(int i)
   {
      string path = GetPath(i);

      //
      List<string> lines = new List<string>();
      string line;

      using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
      {
         while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
            lines.Add(line);
         }

         reader.Close();
         reader.Dispose(); // should I bother?
      }

      return lines;
   }
```

Comment: do you call `lines.Clear()` method?

Comment: 10 x 500 Mb = 5 GB. You are keeping all files contents in the list *List<string> lines*. Same perf as ReadAllLines()

Comment: Garbage Collector won't clear memory if you have pointers to the lines. You must clear() collection after lines were processed

Comment: It is not so, cause there is always a new instance of list with each file and GC should clean up the last one

Comment: you are returning list! what are you doing with it?

Comment: use it as a datsource for further processing.

Comment: @user1514042, I have provided you a solution that allows you to read the entire file at once, perform all processing, and then remove the memory used by storing the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For very large file, method `ReadLines` would be the best fit because it is *deferred execution*, it does not load all lines in memory and simple to use:

```
  Math.Max(max, File.ReadLines(path).Max(line => int.Parse(line)));
```

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

**Edit:**

This is how `ReadLines` implement behind the scene:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string fileName)
    {
        string line;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                yield return line;
        }
    }
```

Also, it is recommended using parallel processing to improve performance when you have multiple files

Comment: Sorry the processing logic is more complex the sample only demonstrates the fact that it's completely decoupled from reading process.

Comment: @user1514042: it does not matter much, you can use it with LINQ to process very large file

Comment: Will it not kill the performance when the actual number of lines is 500K++?

Comment: Quite an elegant solution friend.

Comment: @user1514042, LINQ is just encapsulating the looping for you ... right?

Comment: @user1514042: yes, it deferred execution

Comment: You still have to loop thru them all, don't ya to find the Max?

Comment: @user1514042, LINQ is doing that work for you. The functions that are being used a loops allowing you to operate over the collection. That's what LINQ does ... that's what it was built for. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1514042: Yes, still loop thru to find Max but does not load all in memory to aoid leak

Comment: The `File.ReadLines(path).Max(...` is like my `while` loop inside the `using` statement eh @CuongLe? I'm pretty sure I've got this right ... :)

Comment: @Cuong I put it on trial the results a are rather disappointing, please see the update.

Comment: @user1514042: I meant use `ReadLines` not `ReadAllLines` you are missing the point

Answer (score 4):

You could be crashing because you are keeping references to the parsed result in memory after you are finished processing them (the code you show doesn't do this, but is that the same code you run?). It's highly unlikely that there's such a bug in `StreamReader`.

Are you sure you have to read all the file in memory at once? It might be quite possible to use an enumerable sequence of lines as `IEnumerable<string>` instead of loading up a `List<string>` up front. There is nothing that prohibits this, in this code at least.

Finally, the `Close` and `Dispose` calls are redundant; `using` takes care of that automatically.

Comment: Well I only use value types, can they still hold the reference?

Comment: Of course they can. If you can somehow access the list, someone is holding a reference to it.

Comment: True, but it gets replaced everythime, your point would be right if I was unhappy final 500MB not being cleared, but I have a different problem.

Comment: @user1514042: If you are running out of memory, somewhere there are references that are not being cleared. It's that simple.

Comment: @user1514042, careful in your speech friend. You are certainly not managing memory the way you think you are or you wouldn't be running out of memory. Keep in mind that this line `IEnumerable<string> lines = Db.GetFileLines(i);` literally copies the lists every time but **only** replaces the previous reference, therefore the previous `List<string>` still exists on the heap.

Comment: @user1514042: Very much so. Perhaps you meant to address Mike instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't implement that as following:

```
int max = Int32.MinValue;
using(var reader = File.OpenText(path)) 
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         int current;
         if (Int32.TryParse(line, out current))
             max = Math.Max(max, current);
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the whole file into memmory (List lines )

I guess you could just read a line at a time and keep the highest number?

it will save you a lot of ram.

Comment: Each line takes .5 sec to process, that's why it big time faster to read them up and then process. We gain a lot bu doing that, which is confirmed by performance tests.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are always loading entire file in the memory. At the same time, you are also creating managed objects (List) for each line of the file.

There is no reason that your memory usage will grow.

Please post rest of the code also, I doubt that you are somewhere having reference to this list which is in use and hence it is not being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if you want a solution where you can read the entire file in at once, because you're **sure** that you need that performance gain, then let's do it like this so that way you don't have a memory issue.

```
public static int GetMaxForFile(int i) 
{ 
    string path = GetPath(i); 

    var lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));

    // you MUST perform all of your processing here ... you have to let go
    // of the List<string> variable ...
    int max = Math.Max(max, lines.Max(t=>int.Parse(t)));

    // this may be redundant, but it will cause GC to clean up immediately
    lines.Clear();
    lines = null;

    return max;
}
```