# error on ReadLine for huge file

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, readline, large-files

I have a machine with 32G of memory / windows server 64 bit.

The file is about 30G BUT continuously growing as it is a log file.

I get an Out Of Memory Exception  (on ReadLine), but I don't understand why - as I am just reading into "line" repeatedly. The data is NOT stored after that.

Does ReadLine work in a way I am not expecting? Is it effectively reading the entire file into memory perhaps? Or is it somehow a result of trying to read the last line repeatedly - whilst waiting for the log file to grow?

**EDIT stacktrace as error:**

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at FIXFileReader.FIXFileReader.NextIntraMessage(DateTime& sourceDT) in C:\Projects\OrderManager\OrderManager\FIXFileReader.cs:line 116

```
    private string line;
    private StreamReader;

//edit to give better picture

     txtFileReader = new StreamReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));


while (true)
{

                       while ((line = txtFileReader.ReadLine()) == null)
                        {

                            if (!masterForm.FixFileDataLive)
                            {
                                masterForm.FixFileDataLive=true;
                            }

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

                        }


               // Do processing of line here
               //    < other code >>
               //


}
```

Comment: Consider replacing your StreamReader definition with "[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx)" command in C#. Also this question is probably a duplicate. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415916/read-big-txt-file-out-of-memory-exception) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689284/memory-leak-with-streamreader). Also read [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/277723-problem-reading-large-text-file).

Comment: Have you tried using File.ReadLines instead?

Comment: How long "line" is? Do you see memory usage confirming that you indeed use too much memory?

Comment: How many lines are there in the file? If the file is one line long then readLine will read the entire file.

Comment: @DominikAntal I don't think articles you've linked would help - OP already have equivalent of `ReadLines`... Also first one may hint to actual problem being in some completely unrelated code if result of reading is stored somewhere.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem elsewhere as I used to populate "line" from a socket connection, and the only code that has changed is how I get line. I suspect, just a gut feel, that it has something to do with a cache of txtFileReader growing too large. It does not appear to be reading a line and discarding it after.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Having tested 10GB text file on a laptop with 8GB of memory, the following works with 0 memory issues. Writing the file had LINQPad use no more than 65MB of RAM. Reading the file used no more than 800MB of RAM.

The below code is very similar to your example.

```
void Main()
{
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\Test.txt", true))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }

    // At some point, stop the writing and comment it out and then re-execute with 
    // with the reading code below. I ran the above until I had a 10GB text file.     

    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open("D:\\Test.txt", 
                                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, 
                                                FileShare.ReadWrite)))
    {
        while(true) 
        {
            var line = string.Empty;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting....");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think your issue is with reading the file. It is impossible for us to know exactly what the issue is without more information. Just note that you should still implement `using` if you have not already and that reading the text file seems fine.

**Below is the original answer to the original question**

*Hopefully this is actual code you pasted and didn't just typo stuff when making the question. Otherwise this answer is useless.*

Your `while` condition is wrong. You want to do work while there are lines to read.
You need `!= null` rather than `== null`.

```
while ((line = txtFileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

If you leave as `==`, your program would never actually do anything. Unless of course it couldn't read the first line which would then cause an infinite loop. Perhaps your Out of Memory issue is due to code past this part.

You should also wrap your `txtFileReader` in an `using` statement so it can properly close the stream when you are finished.

Comment: No - I do want ==null, that is  where I wait for file to get more data. I edited my code to give a fuller idea. I can only take a snippet from a much large application.

Comment: @ManInMoon Now that it is shown this is in another main `while` loop, definitely wrap it in a using statement. But still we cannot really help you if we have no idea what it is doing when a line is found. All I can see is that you set the line, do something and then immediately open the file again.... that's bad.

Comment: I am NOT opening file again! It remains open the whole time and then I wait for new data to be added to it.

Comment: @ManInMoon, well not now that you edited your code in the question  =P

Comment: I did that soon after creating - sorry if you missed it.

Comment: @ManInMoon I have written a small test and updated my answer. I don't think your issue lies with reading the text file unless you are not disposing of objects correctly. Either with the StreamReader or other code you have not provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61378/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-tycobb).

Comment: @ManInMoon It is probably related to you reading and writing to that file at the same time or it did run out of memory due to other  objects not being cleaned up. You'll have to start using a memory profiler to see what is happening.